# Why Shakespeare used "come" in the line "A Daniel come to judgement?"

Tags: syntactic-analysis, whiz-deletion

From *The Merchant of Venice*, 1596:

> SHYLOCK: A Daniel **come** to judgment! yea, a Daniel! O wise young judge,
>
> how I do honour thee!

Is it a perfect tense with the auxiliary verb omitted? And is it a common grammatical phenomenon?

Comment: This be a common grammatical phenomenon, yes, but it's rudimentry in English, lumped up under "subjunctive". I don't know the specifics, so no answer. I don't know the context, but it doesn't seem to fit here, if Daniel is already there, which is just another point to show thatbthe subjunctive mood detoriated (due to sound shifts, mostly). I think "is come" can be found as well.

Comment: @vectory It's not a subjunctive: it's an ordinary past participle employed as head of an adjectival clause modifying *Daniel*.

Comment: Cf. a frat-bro come to consciousness.

Answer (score 5):

> A Daniel come to judgment!

Note first that this is not a sentence, a finite clause, but an exclamatory noun phrase, just like the immediately following *Yea, a Daniel!*. *Come to judgment* isn't a predicate but an adjectival modifying *Daniel*.

Your "perfect tense with the auxiliary verb omitted" is a pretty good guess: lots of linguists treat *come to judgment* here as a relative clause 'reduced' by 'Whiz-deletion':

> A Daniel <s>who is</s> come to judgment.

(Note that in Early Modern English the perfect of many intransitive verbs of motion, like  *come*, was constructed with *BE* as the auxiliary: *the Lord is come*.)

I myself do not concur in this parsing: I understand *come* as a past participle deployed as an adjective. Since the verb is intransitive it bears an active rather than a passive sense. ... But it doesn't really matter at this level of analysis which parsing you employ: the sense is the same.

And, yes, it was a common syntactic phenomenon in Shakespeare's day. It is still encountered occasionally, though I think a bit more often in British English than US English:

> Here's a man come about the job you advertised.

Answer (score 1):

As a British English speaker I would consider "come to", that is " has arrived at this place" to be an archaic form and not common usage, except perhaps in legal speak - renowned for its resistance to change!

So:

> A Daniel come to judgment!

This [I think - I don't know the play in detail] is said by Shylock sneeringly and suggests that Daniel has been [found-out](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/find%20out) or judged [possibly in a court of law but probably by the other 'young' character - Shylock is congratulating them on their good judgment - possibly ironically]:

> O wise young judge, how I do honour thee!

I detect some Shakespearian irony at play, Shylock referring to the other character as a "wise young judge", possibly implying in reality, someone that is inexperienced, but that has made a [obvious?] wise decision or come to a good conclusion about the situation [Daniel's motives].

> yea, a Daniel!

Is an abbreviated form of "Yea verily", again an archaic form used widely in Shakespeare's time as:

"An Exclamation used to either [affirm] the [preceding] statement. or to [imply] the statement to be made immediately after has greater significance to the audience in question.

Answer (score -2):

This refers to the Story of Susannah in the Bible who is wrongly accused of adultery by two elders.  Daniel in his wisdom cross examines each separately about what tree she lay under with her lover.  They both gave different answers and Susannah was found innocent.  Shylock being a Jew refers to this story from the Bible in deference to the Wisdom of Daniel.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to ELU. This is a site about the nuts and bolts of the English language. This question is specifically about the word *come* in the quotation, rather than Daniel.